# passing props to another Component and being pushed to variable and being displayed at same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand this method of passing props to a Class and at the same time pushing it into a variable.

```
class Grid extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const width=(this.props.cols*14);
        var rowsarr=[];
        var boxclass="";
        for(var i=0;i<this.props.rows;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<this.props.cols;j++){
                let boxid=i+"_"+j;
                boxclass=this.props.gridfull[i][j]? "box on":"box off";
                rowsarr.push(
                    <Box
                        boxclass={boxclass}
                        key={boxid}
                        boxid={boxid}
                        row={i}
                        col={j}
                        selectbox={this.props.selectbox}
                    />
                );

            }
        }

        return(
         <div className="grid" style={{width:width}}>
             {rowsarr}
             </div>

        );
    }
}
```

In the above code, I see that the props have been passed to the box component but at same it is pushed to rowsarr and rowsarr is being returned.I need an explanation as what is being done here and how this technique works in reactjs.

Comment: Which lines don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it is used to display a list of boxes `<Box>`.
But is is very poorly written.
The common pattern is to iterate on this.props.cols

```
this.props.cols.map(col => <Box> ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

What this code is trying to do is form a grid layout or simply, a list of rows (i) with columns (j).

For every item (Box) - `row i and column j`, the item is inserted into an array, `rowsarr` and different props are passed to it such as `className` etc.

Once the rows and columns are filled in the `rowsarr` array it is passed as the child to `<div className="grid" style={{width:width}}>` so that `<div className="grid">` could render the `rowsarr` elements as its child.

Answer (score 0):

That return method it will return a JSX element which is a div with multiple  elements. Let's deep into it:

```
return(
  <div className="grid" style={{width:width}}>
    {rowsarr}
  </div>
);
```

The above code it's similar to:

```
 return(
      <div className="grid" style={{width:width}}>
       {[ <Box />
        <Box />
        <Box />
        <Box />
        <Box />
       ]}
      </div>
    );
```

Each of this Box class will have different attributes that are calculated based on the props received by Grid Component.

Each box will have different attributes. And each box is put into an array which is put inside of that div. I just asume that Box is a class that returns a div element, so the above code will be rendered as:

```
<div className='grid' style={{width:width}}>
  <div className='box'></div>
  <div className='box'></div>
  <div className='box'></div>
  <div className='box'></div>
  <div className='box'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code creates an array of `<Box>` components and renders them inside a `<div>`. The class name and implementation do not match. This code creates a single row, not an entire grid. There is a mistake in the logic.